# How to fix JSON in R for Option Chains

Tags: json, r

I have been trying to work around the `quantmod::getOptionChain()` since the HTML got updated, [the wrapper fails to return data](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/92)

I have been trying to use the `jsonlite` package to return data but am very confused with the syntax. The following code is what I have so far...

```
library("jsonlite")

# ticker symbol
symbol <- "AAPL"

# Create the URL
url <- paste0('https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/',symbol,'?&date=1471564800')

# call the url
chain = fromJSON(url)
```

The `chain` list looks completely different from the actual url:
`https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/AAPL?&date=1471564800`

What I would like is a data frame with the data. Somehow the data frame should have a new row for each:

```
{"contractSymbol":"AAPL160819C00020000","strike":20.0,"currency":"USD","lastPrice":79.0,"change":0.0,"percentChange":0.0,"volume":50,"openInterest":49,"bid":80.05,"ask":80.6,"contractSize":"REGULAR","expiration":1471564800,"lastTradeDate":1464187329,"impliedVolatility":2.925783935546875,"inTheMoney":true},

{"contractSymbol":"AAPL160819C00030000","strike":30.0,"currency":"USD","lastPrice":64.25,"change":0.0,"percentChange":0.0,"volume":0,"openInterest":3,"bid":62.7,"ask":63.0,"contractSize":"REGULAR","expiration":1471564800,"lastTradeDate":1462388531,"impliedVolatility":1.0000000000000003E-5,"inTheMoney":true},

{"contractSymbol":"AAPL160819C00045000","strike":45.0,"currency":"USD","lastPrice":49.24,"change":0.0,"percentChange":0.0,"volume":0,"openInterest":0,"bid":47.75,"ask":48.05,"contractSize":"REGULAR","expiration":1471564800,"lastTradeDate":1462388543,"impliedVolatility":1.0000000000000003E-5,"inTheMoney":true},
```

Ex:

```
Contract Symbol        strike   currency   lastPrice   Change   percentChange ...
AAPL160819C00020000    20.0      USD         79.0       0.0        0.0 ...
AAPL160819C00030000    30.0      USD         64.25      0.0        0.0 ...
AAPL160819C00045000    45.0      USD         49.24      0.0        0.0 ...
```

The header of the json that has the P/E ratios, moving average, etc would be nice to incorporate into the data frame as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lot of nesting within the list you have, and converting from json directly wouldnt yield the desired results. So you have to manually see what information you want inside each list and then extract it.

```
mylist=chain$optionChain$result$options
mydf=as.data.frame(mylist)
calls=mydf$calls
```